# Plugin to count file download

Tags: plugin-recommendation, statistics

I'm looking for a plugin which will allow me to count how many times a file has been downloaded. I don't need neither a fancy download page nor showing the download count on the page itself, I want it just for me. I'm aware that GA can track them but if the user right-click the link it might not detect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a plugin (or another piece of software) that tracks the actual server logs. If you don't need WordPress integration there are many options, [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a classic for Apache and other server log formats. I don't know whether there are plugins that integrate nicely with WordPress (normalizing URLs to posts and stuff like that). [WP-Alp](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-alp/) seems to only display bandwidth usage.

Comment: Considering you want to track downloads even if the user right-clicks on the link, this is the **only** way to go.  Any kind of front-end download tracker (GA or any kind of WordPress plug-in) will not be able to track when people right-click to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use plugin that sets up redirect links and tracks clicks count. It won't work if someone links directly to file, but will track clicks from site reliably.

Yoast.com had recently recommended [Simple URLs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-urls/) by StudioPress for such redirects.